# Where can I find the soure code for /system/bin/input?

Tags: android

This question was originally posted on Android stackexchange, and someone suggested moving it here.

I would like to make an enhanced copy of /system/bin/input, but a simple google search does not turn up where it lies in the android source tree.

Can someone link me or provide the directory where the source is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the complete code inside my /system/bin/input file

```
# Script to start "input" on the device, which has a very rudimentary
# shell.
#
base=/system
export CLASSPATH=$base/framework/input.jar
exec app_process $base/bin com.android.commands.input.Input $*
```

Comment: Located at: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-7.1.1_r22/cmds/input/input and then Input.java: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.1.1_r22/cmds/input/src/com/android/commands/input/Input.java Found with: google `android "exec app_process $base/bin com.android.commands.input.Input"` and `android "The commands and default sources are"`.